# Can White win the endgame from game Kramnik-Carlsen, London 2010?

Tags: analysis, endgame, carlsen, kramnik

```
[Title "White to move"]
[fen "8/6p1/7p/2k5/8/p5P1/B5P1/6K1 w - - 0 1"]
```

Can White win this endgame?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [analysis of GM Mueller](http://en.chessbase.com/portals/4/files/news/2010/london/games/lcc08.htm), white is winning.

The game went: 65.Kf2 Kd4 66.Kf3 Kd3 67.g4 Kd2 68.Be6 Kd3.
And now 69.g5! wins in all the lines, while Kramnik played 69.Kg3?, after which the ending is drawn.

The entire game, with the analysis of GM Mueller:

```
[FEN ""]
[Event "2nd London Chess Classic"]
[Site "London ENG"]
[Date "2010.12.14"]
[Round "6"]
[White "Kramnik, Vladimir"]
[Black "Carlsen, Magnus"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]
[ECO "D07"]
[WhiteElo "2791"]
[BlackElo "2802"]
[Annotator "Müller,Karsten"]
[PlyCount "171"]
[EventDate "2010.12.06"]
[EventType "tourn"]
[EventRounds "7"]
[EventCountry "ENG"]
[EventCategory "19"]
[StartPly "128"]

1. d4 d5 2. c4 Nc6 3. Nf3 Bg4 4. Nc3 e6 5. Bf4 Bd6 6. Bg3 Nf6 7. e3 O-O 8. a3
Ne7 9. Qb3 b6 10. Ne5 c5 11. Nxg4 Nxg4 12. Rd1 Bxg3 13. hxg3 Nf6 14. cxd5 exd5
15. Be2 Qd6 16. Qc2 h6 17. O-O c4 18. b3 Qxa3 19. bxc4 dxc4 20. Bf3 Rab8 21.
Ra1 Qd6 22. Nb5 Qd7 23. Qxc4 a5 24. e4 Rfc8 25. Qe2 Rc6 26. Rab1 Rd8 27. Rfd1
Rdc8 28. d5 Rc2 29. Qe3 R2c5 30. Nd4 Re8 31. Qd3 Qd6 32. Qa6 Rb8 33. Nb3 Rc2
34. Nd4 Rc5 35. Nb3 Rc2 36. Qd3 Rcc8 37. Nd2 Ng6 38. Be2 Qc5 39. Rb5 Qc3 40. f4
a4 41. e5 Nd7 42. Qxc3 Rxc3 43. Ne4 Rc7 44. Ra1 Ra7 45. d6 Ngf8 46. Nc3 Nc5 47.
Nd5 Ra5 48. Rxb6 Rxb6 49. Nxb6 Nfe6 50. Bc4 Kf8 51. f5 Nd8 52. Rf1 Ncb7 53. Re1
a3 54. e6 fxe6 55. fxe6 Nxd6 56. e7+ Ke8 57. exd8=R+ Kxd8 58. Rd1 Kc7 59. Ba2
Rg5 60. Nd5+ Kc6 61. Nc3 {#} Rc5 62. Rxd6+ Kxd6 63. Ne4+ Kc6 64. Nxc5 Kxc5 {#}
65. Kf2 Kd4 66. Kf3 Kd3 67. g4 Kd2 68. Be6 Kd3 {#} {A miraculous escape. It is
hard to believe that Magnus Carlsen got away with a draw despite being down a
piece.} 69. Kg3 $2 {Kramnik allows the king to penetrate too deeply.} (69. g5 $1 {Hiarcs 13, running on a 12-core machine and providing added information to the live commentary, calmly spat out a mate score with an irreductible winning line.
Here it is with some added analysis to clarify.} hxg5 (69... h5 70.
Kf4 Kd4 71. g3 Kc5 72. Kf5 Kd6 73. Ba2 Ke7 74. Kg6 Kf8 75. Kh7 $18) 70. g3 {
opening the gates to the deadly endgame weapon: the Zugzwang, which takes the
day once more.} Kd4 71. Kg4 Ke3 72. Kxg5 {#and here all attempts to defeat the
triangulation with the bishop will fail.} Kf3 (72... Kf2 73. Kf4 Kg2 74. g4 Kh3
75. g5+ Kh4 76. Kf5 Kh3 (76... Kh5 77. Bf7+ Kh4 78. Ba2 Kh5 79. Be6 Kh4 80. Kg6
) 77. Bb3 Kh4 78. Ba2 Kh5 79. Be6 Kh4 80. Kg6) 73. Kh4 g6 74. Bf7 g5+ 75. Kh3
Kf2 76. Kg4 Kg2 {and now a triangulation with the bishop wins it.} 77. Ba2 Kf2
78. Bd5 $18) 69... Ke3 70. Kh4 (70. g5 {is no longer good enough. Ex:} Ke4 (
70... Kd4 $2 71. Kf4 hxg5+ 72. Kxg5 Ke3 73. Kf5 Kf2 74. g4 Kg3 75. g5 Kh4 76.
Kg6 $18) (70... h5 $2 71. Kh4 g6 72. g4 hxg4 73. Kxg4 Ke4 74. Ba2 Ke5 75. Bf7
$18) (70... hxg5 $2 71. Kg4 Kf2 72. g3 Kg2 73. Ba2 Kf2 74. Bd5 Ke3 75. Kxg5 Kd4
76. Ba2 Ke4 77. Kg4 Ke3 78. Bb1 Kf2 79. Kf4 Kg2 80. Ba2 Kf2 81. g4 Kg2 82. g5
Kh3 83. Kf5 Kh4 84. Bb3 Kh5 85. Be6 Kh4 86. Kg6 $18) 71. Kg4 Ke5 72. Ba2 Ke4
73. g3 Ke3 74. Bb1 Kf2 75. g6 h5+ 76. Kxh5 Ke3 77. Kg5 Kd4 78. Kf5 Kd5 79. Ba2+
Kd6 {and Black has succeeded in securing the draw.}) 70... Kf2 71. Bd5 (71. Kh5
{fails because the white bishop is overwhelmed after} Kxg2 72. Kg6 Kg3 73. Kxg7
a2 74. Bxa2 Kxg4 75. Kxh6 $11) 71... g6 72. Kh3 g5 $1 $11 {White cannot leave
the kingside without losing the g4 pawn.} 73. Kh2 Kf1 74. Be6 Kf2 75. Bc4 Ke3
76. Kg3 Kd4 77. Be6 Ke3 78. Kh2 Kf2 79. Bc4 Ke3 80. Kg1 Kf4 81. Be6 Ke5 82. Bb3
Kf4 83. Be6 Ke5 84. Bb3 Kf4 85. Be6 Ke5 86. Bb3 1/2-1/2
```

Comment: Upvoted and officially accepted. The lines are instructive and very entertaining. Thanks.

Comment: Nice. Would have been even nicer with a diagram. Cheers.

Comment: Good idea! I'll add one.

Comment: I added the game. How can I let the viewer start from move 65? The viewer doesn't show the comments, how can this be fixed? Feel free to edit the answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Stephen Thanks for the edit! And it seems that the comments are shown in the box below the diagram.